# Unequal left and right margins in beamer with alignat

Tags: beamer, math-mode, align, margins

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{frame}[shrink]
  \onslide<+->\raggedright{%
  The nos. from 1 to 140 which are divisible by 4 are 4, 8, 12, ... 140.

  }
  \begin{alignat*}{5}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{ &= 2520}
  \end{alignat*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When compiled, it produces a document with clearly different left and right margins.

Remove a copule of rows and the margins become equal.

How do I ensure that the left and right margins are equal no matter the length of text?

Answer (score 1):

The cause is actually the `shrink` option. You can alternative rescale the `alignat` env:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{frame}
  \onslide<+->\raggedright{%
  The nos. from 1 to 140 which are divisible by 4 are 4, 8, 12, ... 140.

  }
\scalebox{.9}{\parbox{1.11\textwidth}{
  \begin{alignat*}{5}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{t_n &= a + (n - 1)d \\}
    \onslide<+->{ &= 2520}
  \end{alignat*}
}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]